# Java - Castor XML mapping : how to concatenate two Java field values into one XML attribute value and vice versa

Tags: java, xml, mapping, concatenation, castor

Consider the following period : 2017-11-03 to 2017-11-06

- The XML has one element : TimePeriodCovered: v="2017-11-03T00:00Z/2017-11-06T00:00Z" which is a concatenation of two dates ;
- The Java object maps this field with two attributes (Date) : startPeriod & endPeriod

## .java

```
public class foo implements Serializable {

    private Date startPeriod;

    private Date endPeriod;

    ...
}
```

## .xsd

```
<xs:element name="container" >
    <xs:complexType>
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="foo" type="fooType" />
            ...
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>


<xs:complexType name="fooType">
    <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="TimePeriodCovered" minOccurs="0" type="PeriodType" />
        ...
    </xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>

<xs:complexType name="PeriodType">
    <xs:attribute name="v" use="required">
        <xs:simpleType>
            <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
                <xs:pattern value="[1-2][0-9][0-9][0-9]-[0-1][0-9]-[0-3][0-9]T[0-2][0-9]:[0-6][0-9]Z?/[1-2][0-9][0-9][0-9]-[0-1][0-9]-[0-3][0-9]T[0-2][0-9]:[0-6][0-9]Z?" />
            </xs:restriction>
        </xs:simpleType>
    </xs:attribute>
</xs:complexType>
```

## mapping.xml

I have absolutely no idea. What should it be ?

Comment: This is a design flaw. The according code smell is called "primitive obsession". You should change the XML to be a *complexType* with two attributes (*from* and *to*) which could be converted to Javas `Date` type be *JaxB* directly.

Comment: Okay but in the end I really need to have an element like TimePeriodCovered: v="2017-11-03T00:00Z/2017-11-06T00:00Z". So what should I do, as you said and then use a XSLT ?"

Comment: *"I really need to have an element like TimePeriodCovered"* Why? can't you convince the creator of the XSD that her approach is flawed?

Comment: No because the company I work for is very big and thus use an EAI to collect and dispatch files between various applications. And this XSD is a EAI format, so it does not concern my application specifically. I cannot alter the foo class nor the xsd, so besides a XSL transformation I don't know what I can do, but it feels wrong.

Comment: Did you see the documentation? http://castor-data-binding.github.io/castor/reference-guides/1.3.3/html-single/index.html#xml.mapping.mappingfile especially **1.2.3.6.1. Mapping constructor arguments**?

Comment: Yes I did. I tried to define a setter and getter method for the java field named TimePeriodCovered (of course it doesn't exist) : 

    <field name="TimePeriodCovered" type="string">
        <bind-xml name="v" location="TimePeriodCovered" node="attribute" />
    </field>

I created the setter to receive the string "2017-11-03T00:00Z/2017-11-06T00:00Z" and then extract and convert each String of Date into proper java.util.Date and set the fields "from" and "to". Similarly I created the getter to return the string "2017-11-03T00:00Z/2017-11-06T00:00Z" using the fields "from" and "to".

Comment: Unfortunately it did not work as I had an exception telling me that getTimePeriodCovered/setTimePeriodCovered  could not be found. I think it as nothing to do with the fact that the field doesn't exist, because the documentation says **"The field ‘name’ is required even if no such field exists in the class"**. I don't know what went wrong.

In the end I will just marshall a xml with the elements "from" and "to" and then use a xslt to create a single element TimePeriodCovered. Thank you very much for you help.